# If $g\in C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, show $\lim_{x\to+\infty }\int_0^1x^ndg(x)=0$

Tags: analysis, integration

Suppose $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that  $g\in C^1$ (i.e., $g'$ exists and is continuous). I want to show $$\lim_{n\to+\infty }\int_0^1x^ndg(x)=0.$$ Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168163/find-functions-family-satisfying-lim-n-to-infty-n-int-01-xn-fx-f1) that yields
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\times n\int_0^1x^ndg(x)\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty } \frac{g'(1)}{n}=0$$

Comment: Nice, +1. I think the OP means $dg(x)=g'(x)dx$, so your numerator should simply be $g'(1)$.

Comment: @chriss-sister thanks

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: welcome!

Comment: @chriss sister:whats error? .yes its $\lim_{n\to+\infty }$

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: there was $"x"$ instead of $"n"$ in your post. Now it's corrected.

Comment: @chriss sister:i check it my question is true .but i think your answer is true according to refered question

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 6):

This is trivial by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

And pretty straightforward as follows.
Let $M$ be the max of $|g'|$ on $[0,1]$.
Then
$$
|\int_0^1x^ng'(x)dx|\leq M\int_0^1 x^ndx=\frac{M}{n+1}.
$$
Conclude by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: :thanks your answer is nice too

Comment: @julien: +1 for your fast way.

Comment: @julien:why g' is bounded ?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo You said that $g'$ was continuous, and $[0,1]$ is compact.

Comment: @julien:thanks i understand it .