# Normal Integration methods failing. $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right){\rm d}x$

Tags: integration

The task is not to evaluate these, but something else which you would come to know after reading to the end of the post.

$\newcommand{\u}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\i}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}\left(#1\right){\rm d}#2}
\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\sb}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$

Let us define: $$f(n)=\i{x^{n-1}\sin\b{\frac{\pi x}2}}{x}{0}{1}\\
g(n)=\i{x^{n-1}\cos\b{\frac{\pi x}2}}{x}{0}{1}$$
Now I change the variable, $t=\pi x/2$:
$$f(n)=\u{\b{\frac2\pi}^n}{\zeta}\u{\i{t^{n-1}\sin t}{t}0{\pi/2}}{F(n)}$$
Similiarly:
$$g(n)=\u{\b{\frac2\pi}^n}{\zeta}\u{\i{t^{n-1}\cos t}{t}0{\pi/2}}{G(n)}$$
Now Let us integrate by parts:
$$F(n)=\sb{t^{n-1}(-\cos t)}_0^{\pi/2}-\i{(n-1)t^{n-2}(-\cos t)}{t}0{\pi/2}$$
So:
$$F(n)=(n-1)G(n-1)$$
Now I need to find these:
$$\xi_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}{(n+1)f(n)}$$
And:
$$\xi_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n+1)f(n)}{(2n+1)^2g(n)}$$
The second one can be done as:
$$\xi_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n+1)\zeta (n-1)G(n-1)}{(2n+1)^2\zeta G(n)}$$
And I think that $\lim_{n\to\infty}G(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}G(n)$ [No proof, intuitive] that $\xi_2=\frac34$

---

**Questions:**

- Is $\xi_2$ correct?
- What advice/hint would you give me to find $\xi_1$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure xi_1 diverges. The zeta part grows exponentially, whereas the F(n) approaches 1.

Comment: @HarryWilson see math110's answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1),use this well known result
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}f(x)dx=f(1).f\in C[0,1]$$
see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455193/for-f-continuous-show-lim-n-to-infty-n-int-01-fxxn-dx-f1)

for $(2)$,we have general 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{1}g(x)[f(x)]^{n+1}dx}{\int_{0}^{1}g(x)[f(x)]^ndx}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}\{f(x)\};f,g\in C[0,1],{\rm{and}}\; f,g>0$$
so let $g(x)=\cos{\frac{\pi x}{2}},f(x)=x$,we have
$$\xi_{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(3n+1)(n-1)g(n-1)}{(2n+1)^2g(n)}=\dfrac{3}{4}\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{x\in [0,1]}x=\dfrac{3}{4}$$

Comment: atleast not known to me, or many such people at my level.

Comment: ok I got 1st what about proof of 2nd