# The value of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, limits

The value of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}nx^ne^{x^2}dx$ is _____

I tried by taking the odd $n$ values as in that case, the integral I suppose was easier to calculate.
So, denote $I_n=n\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}x^ndx$, then we have : $I_1=\frac{e-1}{2},\\I_3=\frac{3}{2},\\I_5=5(\frac{e}{2}-1),\\I_7=7(3-e)$

Then I tried calculating (random) values using calculator as integration was getting cumbersome. $I_{31}=2.488$, $I_{51}=2.57$.

I do not see any kind of recurrence so that I can find a general term for odd $n$. I also tried the method given [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/). The idea was that since integral doesn't depend on $n$ considering $I(n)=\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}x^ndx$, then $I'(n)=\int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln(x)e^{x^2}dx$, but this also doesn't lead me to any conclusion as well.

I believe I couldn't get to a proper approach to tackle this question. Can someone please help with the idea that involves in solving these type of questions?

Comment: This is related to the concept of [*approximation to the identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function). In general, if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}nx^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=f(1).$$ For this reason, we may simply say that $nx^n\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges to the unit point mass $\delta_1(\mathrm{d}x)$ on $[0,1]$. For the proof, check [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455193/9340).

Comment: Replace $nx^n$ with $(n+1)x^n$ and do integration by parts.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly
$$\int_0^1 nx^n\,dx\le I_n\le e\int_0^1 nx^n\,dx.$$
Thus
$$\frac{n}{n+1}\le I_n\le e\frac{n}{n+1}.$$
So, if the limit exists, it's between $1$ and $e$ (and certainly is non-zero).

Most of the weight of the integral $I_n$ comes from near $1$, so for $\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}\ep>0$ we have
$$I_n\ge\int_{1-\ep}^1nx^n e^{x^2}\,dx\ge e^{(1-\ep)^2}\int_{1-\ep}^1nx^n\,dx
=e^{(1-\ep)^2}\frac n{n+1}(1-(1-\ep)^{n+1}).$$
Then $\liminf I_n\ge e^{(1-\ep)^2}$, and this is enough to deduce $\lim I_n=e$.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfralm Alpha calculates

$$\int_0^1nx^ne^{x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{2}i^{1-n}n\Bigg(\Gamma\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2}\bigg)-\Gamma\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2},-1\bigg)\Bigg)$$

No clue if this monstrosity can be simplified, but again using Wolfram alpha to find the lmit, it says

> (no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)

Yet it gives us a series expansion at $n=\infty$

$$\Bigg(e-\frac{3e}{n}+\frac{13e}{n^2}-\frac{71e}{n^3}+\frac{547e}{n^4}+O\Big(\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)^5\Big)\Bigg)+2^{-n/2}e^{-n(1+\pi i)/2}n^{n/2}O\Big(\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)^{11/2}\Big)$$

So perhaps the limit is just $e$ or $e-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, the function $n x^n$, for $n$ large, concentrates its mass $n/(n+1)$ near $x=1$ (you can think it like a Dirac delta concentrated in $x=1$), so that the sequence converges to $e$.

To prove rigorously this statement, let $0<a<1$ and split the integral into
$$
I_n = \int_0^a f_n(x)\, dx,
\quad
J_n = \int_0^a f_n(x)\, dx,
\qquad f_n(x) := n x^n e^{x^2}.
$$
Since, in $[0,a]$, the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $0$, we have that
$I_n \to 0$.

On the other hand,
$$
n\, x^n\, e^{a^2} \leq f_n(x) \leq n\, x^n
\qquad \forall x\in [a,1],
$$
hence
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}\, e^{a^2} \leq J_n \leq \frac{n}{n+1}\, e, \qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Since these inequalities hold for every $a\in (0,1)$, we can finally conclude that the initial limit is $e$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer because it was a duplicate somewhere else.

Simple partial integration gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}I_n =\int_0^1nx^ne^{x^2}dx
& = & \frac n{n-1}\int_0^1(n-1)x^ne^{x^2}dx \\
& = & \frac n{n-1}\left(\left.x^ne^{x^2}\right|_0^1-2\int_0^1x^{n+1}e^{x^2}dx\right)\\
& = & \frac n{n-1}\left(e-J_n\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

with

$$0\leq J_n \leq 2e\int_0^1x^{n+1}dx =\frac{2e}{n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Hence, $\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n = e}$.