# Find the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} nx^n e^{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, uniform-convergence

Find the value of   $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} nx^n e^{x^2}dx$

I am trying to solve this by using uniform convergence rule for integration but getting nothing , i have solved questions with negative exponential ,because it is easy to find their uniform convergence ,but here i am not getting any idea how to solve this, please  give me a hint so that i can try it myself,

Thank you.

Comment: Look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751785/the-value-of-lim-n-to-infty-int-01nxnex2dx?rq=1)

Comment: Thankyou @ChinnapparajR.

Comment: I have added an answer to the linked page which is far easier than the other ones presented there.